# How to style TabPane dropdown menu in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx-8

I want to style JavaFX TabPane dropdown menu. The menu, which appears when there is too much tabs to fit to screen. I have found this substructure in java documentation.

> - tab-header-area — StackPane
>
>   - headers-region — StackPane
>   - tab-header-background — StackPane
>   - control-buttons-tab — StackPane
>
>     - tab-down-button — Pane
>
>       - arrow — StackPane
>   - tab — Tab
>
>     - tab-label — Label
>     - tab-close-button — StackPane
> - tab-content-area — StackPane

But there is nothing about the dropdown menu. So is there any way to style this with css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too late to the party, but this might help someone. You can access the tabs menu using this code:

```
// Access the tabs menu itself
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab > .container > .tab-down-button .context-menu {
    // Do something.
}

// Access menu item
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab > .container > .tab-down-button .context-menu .radio-menu-item {
    // Do something.
}

 // Access menu item's text
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab > .container > .tab-down-button .context-menu .radio-menu-item .label {
    // Do something.
}

 // Access menu item's check sign
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab > .container > .tab-down-button .context-menu .radio-menu-item .left-container .radio {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the dropmenu with the class `.context-menu` in the CSS file.
For example you can change the background color of the drop-down menu using this code snippet:

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #d0d0d0;
}
```

Comment: One thing to not here is that this will work for change the `background-color` for every context menu.

if we want to change context menu settings for any element, we can do it by `.element-name > .context-menu` like mentioned in above answer `.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .control-buttons-tab > .container > .tab-down-button`